# $(x,y)$-primary ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

> I want to find all ideals $I$ in $\mathbf{C}[x,y]$ with $\sqrt{I}=(x,y)$ and $\dim_{\mathbf{C}}\mathbf{C}[x,y]/I=2$.

I have no clue how to about it, I mean I can write down some examples, $I=(x,y^2)$ say, but in the general I failed. What I know about $I$ is that it contains some power of $x$ and some power of $y$, and that it is f.g., and in a sense the powers should not be that high so as to assure the dimension to be 2. Could someone help me?

Remark: I have seen a related question for the dimension $4$ case, but I have no idea what a Gröbner basis is, I want a hands on approach.

Comment: Try to prove  that the required ideals are the ideals $( y-ax,x^2)$ with $a\in \mathbb C$ and the ideal $(x,y^2)$ you already know.

Comment: Dear @zcn, my ideals are all different and  exactly parametrize the required ideals: the investigated  ideals  form a one-dimensional family ( a $\mathbb P^1$ actually) . Your family in contrast is highly redundant:  you use four parameters: three too many. For example your $(x+y, (-2x+y)^2)$ is equal to your *apparently* different $(x+y, y^2)$ but both are equal to my  $(y+x, x^2)$.

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg: You are absolutely correct! I will remove my previous erroneous comment (at the risk of losing continuity). Thank you kindly for your helpful comments

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ be such an ideal. Then $\{1,x,y\}$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-linearly dependent spanning set of $R := \mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$ (since $1 \not \in I$), so $ax + by + c \in I \subseteq (x,y)$ for some $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$ not all $0 \implies c = 0$, so there is a nonzero linear form $ax + by \in I$. By a linear change of coordinates $x' := ax + by, y' := cx + dy$ with $ad - bc \ne 0$ we may assume $x \in I$.

Thus $\{1, y\}$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-basis for $R$. Thus $y^2 - ry - s \in I \subseteq (x,y)$ for some $r, s \in \mathbb{C} \implies s = 0$. For $n := \min\{ t \mid y^t \in I\} \ge 2$, multiplying by $y^{n-2}$ gives $y^n \equiv ry^{n-1} \pmod I \implies r = 0$, so in fact $y^2 \in I$. Then $(x,y^2) \subseteq I$, so there is a surjection of $2$-dim $\mathbb{C}$-vector spaces $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x,y^2) \twoheadrightarrow R$, which is an isomorphism, so $I = (x,y^2)$.

Thus, the $(x,y)$-primary ideals $I \subseteq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ of degree $2$ are associated to a matrix in $GL_2(\mathbb{C}$) via $\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix} \leftrightarrow (ax + by, (cx + dy)^2)$; i.e. $I = (f_1, f_2^2)$, where $f_1, f_2$ are independent linear forms vanishing at $0$.

**Edit:** As Georges points out, there is some redundancy here, as $(f_1, f_2^2) = (r_1f_1, r_2(f_2 - r_3f_1)^2)$ for $r_i \ne 0$. Thus
$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}$ gives the same ideal as
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & b \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ (if $a \ne 0$) or $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ (if $a = 0$), and these matrices, parametrized by $\mathbb{P}^1$ (the first row), give rise to distinct ideals.

Comment: A few notes: nothing special about the field $\mathbb{C}$ was used in this answer, and the conclusion implies that all such schemes are isomorphic

Comment: This is correct but there are many repetitions of the same ideal in this description: see my comment to the question.